# Datagridview contains cell value as object but i need property?

Tags: c#, datagridview

k is instance of class Card and each row in datagridview contains all 3 its properties. I would like to read each property, and insert that instance in list.

```
public List<Card> insertInList()
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //I considered 'row.Cells[i].Value' - this returns object,               
                //and I need int, or string
                Card k = new Card();
                //k.Id =?;
                //k.Word =?;
                //k.Description =?;
                list1.Add(k);
                return list1;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: If you have gridview with fixed number of columns and you know which column has which property value of cart then you should not have inner loop. You should use `row.Cells[0].Value`, `row.Cells[1].Value` etc and convert those value to target type of the property and assigning it to the property of cart.

Comment: Great! I wasnt sure what is number of first column in dgv. so its 0.

Answer (score 0):

this should be solution:

```
public List<Karta> insertInList()
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {

                Card k = new Card();
                k.Id =(int)row.Cells[0].Value;
                k.Word =(string) row.Cells[1].Value;
                k.Description = (string)row.Cells[2].Value;
                List.Add(k);


     }
 return List;
}
```